# How to watch videos in Chromium?

Tags: 14.04, sound, video, chromium

I can't see videos in Chromium in Ubuntu 16.04. How can I fix that?

```
http://www.quizover.com/oer/course/adaptive-submodularity-a-new-approach-to-by-daniel-videolectures
```

[image]

```
jalal@klein:~$ dpkg-query -s adobe-flashplugin
dpkg-query: package 'adobe-flashplugin' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
jalal@klein:~$ sudo apt-get install  adobe-flashplugin
[sudo] password for jalal: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate
```

I installed this:
sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
YouTube videos play with no sound.
Please suggest fixes.

UPDATE: I added these, updated and installed flash but I can't hear video voices still:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list

     48 deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
     49 deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: Enable [Canonical Parner](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner). Then you can install `adobe-flashplugin`. (`browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` is for Firefox and redundant if you use Chromium.)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson please see the update!

Comment: even though flash is installed the video is played there is no sound

Comment: Maybe you just need to restart Chromium?